# How to Java cache in-Memory by group/tag data?

Tags: java, caching, data-structures, ehcache

I read about Java Cache in-Memory, and see almost solutions are [ key => value ]. But it's not enough when we need manipulate more pieces data. Example:

```
{
    key: "book1", //1 is book id
    value: {
        id: 1,
        name: "Book's name",
        author: "Book's author",
    }
},
{
    key: "book2",
    value: {
        id: 2,
        name: "Book's name",
        author: "Book's author",
    }
},
{
    key: "book3",
    value: {
        id: 3,
        name: "Book's name",
        author: "Book's author",
    }
}
```

How do I get all of theme without know exactly id to build the key : "book"+id.
Is there any way to tag item, and we can get all by tag name.

```
{
    key: "book3",
    tag: "recentBook"
    value: {
        id: 3,
        name: "Book's name",
        author: "Book's author",
    }
}
```

I expect you to offer any solutions organization structure for cache data OR a library support to work with tag/group data. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

For an indexed access and for storage of data you need a database, not a cache. The cache, by concept, is just to speed up things and all data in the cache is of temporary nature. This means, by design contract, the cache may hold the data for "book3" or evict it at any time if there is a resource shortage and the caching of other books yields better overall performance.

Cache solutions may offer persistence as an option. The usage for this is to have a larger capacity and to preserve the cache content across restarts. The persistence functionality has not the same quality as databases, e.g. there is no data migration of on disk data structures when the cache solution is upgraded. The same holds for robustness against data loss, e.g. on a power outage.

So first check if it is better in your scenario to use a database. There are "tiny" databases for Java e.g. LevelDB oder MapDB.

You can "misuse" the cache as your primary storage, e.g. if you set the capacity limits high enough. In this case you could have a second cache that maps a tag to book IDs. You can either update this cache, whenever a book is updated. The other approach would be to create the cache content by iterating over all books.

Comment: Actually I used cache to keep items in-memory, and after a period of time I insert all of them into database. But I think your "A Second Cache For Index" solution is good!